# OSX context menu and popups look strange

Tags: macos, high-sierra

For some time, I noticed that the appearance of the Mac OS context menu (right-click menu) and popups changed.

[image]
[image]

They look like in older OSX versions. In the upper picture, the corners should be rounded; in the lower picture, the blue should be different.

I don't really know why this changed or whether it's an editable setting. 
I think that this behavior occurred after updating some Adobe programs (After Effects, Dimension CC, etc.).

My current OSX version is 10.13.6, on a MBP (late 2016, 15").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a long time, I found out that the actual behavior **is** a setting:

*System Settings -> Accessibility -> Display -> Reduce Transparency ->* ***On/Off***

If you turn *Reduce Transparency* off, the usual, normal context menu will appear again. I have no idea who or what changed this setting.